# bash - How to keep launching a program until it exits with 0

Tags: linux, bash

Wrote a python script that does a task that may be running for a few hours. Since it communicates with a remote server, the script may fail if there's a connection error. What I'd like to do is to keep relaunching it if its exit code is not 0. Is it possible with bash?

Some pseudo-C if my wording is not clear:

```
int exitcode;
do
{
    exitcode = MyPythonScript();
} while (exitcode != 0);
```

Comment: Instead of relaunching the program from bash, you should catch the connection error in the python program and reconnect in that case.

Comment: @hek2mgl, I absolutely agree that this would be a much better solution. However, the code that does the network stuff is not mine, I merely call a function from a lib. That makes me unsure whether I can do anything about the connection error without modifying the lib itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
until MyPythonScript
do
    : Nothing
done
```

That exits when the command exits with a true (success) status.  You can put a sleep, or an error report, or anything else you want in the body of the loop in place of the 'do nothing but always succeed' command `:`.  You can add arguments to the script as desired, of course (and I/O redirections, etc).

Comment: Super elegant solution!

Comment: Instead of the `: Nothing` (which is really just a `:` with a discarded argument), you can also sleep (like `sleep 10` to sleep for 10 seconds), which is frequently a good idea to avoid network spamming and wasted processor cycles.